# how to transfert informations from one view to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have this view in my app
http://hpics.li/ce94f6c
the user should put the fly number and he will get informations taht i got from a web service in the table view .
But this table view is small and i want to make one at the height and width of the vie .
Should i hide the label and button and then show the large table view ?
Or should i make a new xib and load it when the user click the button ?
or should i create a new tableviewcontroller with .xib and send to him the json to parase and put in the table view ?

help please

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Any of the options you list could work. The right one depends upon your design goals. You should give one of them a try and see what you think. If you find that you don't know how to implement it, then you can ask for help about that specific task. Good luck!

Comment: 1. Does the value entered into the field relate to the table (would a user need to see both at the same time for the information to be worthwhile)? 2. Will the data in the table be rows that are selectable? For example, once the table is populated with the data, does the user need to click on a specific row to drill down to more data? Perhaps a modal view of the table results? 3. (Note: I can't read French) is the input field a static value (like a frequent flyer number) or does it change a each time? If it's static - perhaps save to a location in the app (or to the app settings?)

Comment: thank you for response .
@CharlieMezak ok but i asked for the correct and most used method .The question is vague because i don't have any idea how i will proceed.
@ Kolya Miller  1) No , and the entered value will be in the json result .
2) No but i will make a save button and i will put them in a file or database .
Sorry but i don't understand your last question ( is the input field a static value …). The user will enter a value , see the result and save it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to go with your second option.

1. You can firstly create a ViewController where you have a label and a button field. (You should also put some image is this case as having only a button and a label on complete screen will seem to be odd).
2. Once you click the button you can call the web service and then navigate to a new viewController where you can display web results in a tableView.